# control difference of inverses of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

Let $f$ and $g$ be smooth functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself. How to express $f^{-1}(0)-g^{-1}(0)$ in terms of $f$ and $g$? Preferably, in terms of $f-g$. Here $f^{-1}$ means the inverse function.
The motivation for my question is that I want to control $f^{-1}(0)-g^{-1}(0)$ under the assumption $f$ and $g$ are very close in some sense.

Comment: just a guess, but maybe using some combination of the difference quotient and the formula for the derivative of an inverse in terms of the derivative of the function?

Comment: This much depends on what you mean by $f$ and $g$ be “very close”.

Comment: @egreg For example, $|f-g|$ is uniformly bounded by a small number. This is not very import, as I just want an expression relating the two kinds of differences.

Comment: Assume $f$ is a $C^1$ near $0$ and $f'(0)\ne 0$ , then we may assume $f(x) = x$ wlog. Now, apply Taylor theorem on $g^{-1}(0) = g^{-1}(g(0) + f(0) - g(0))$. You will obtain a bound depending on the $C^1$ norm of $f-g$ near $0$.